# Adapting mysql query to mssql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, codeigniter

The query running on Mysql, it is not running on mssql. How can I fix this problem.

```
SELECT
Count(*) AS stok_adet, 
s.*, 
m.*, 
d.* 
FROM stok AS s 
CROSS JOIN mermer_cins AS m 
JOIN stok_durum AS d 
ON s.stok_durum_id = d.stok_durum_id 
WHERE  m.mermer_cins_id = '5' 
AND s.blok_no = 'M6320' 
GROUP  BY s.bundle_no, 
s.boy, 
s.yukseklik, 
s.hatali 
ORDER  BY s.blok_no ASC, 
s.bundle_no ASC, 
s.stok_tarih DESC
```

Comment: @newline . . . Your MySQL query is malformed (it would generate an error in more recent versions of MySQL using default settings).  Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would all help.

Answer (score 4):

Your code shouldn't work on MySQL either -- at least using the default settings that have been standard for several years.

Do not use `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY`.  It is best to just list the columns

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as stok_adet,
       s.bundle_no, s.boy, s.yukseklik, s.hatali
FROM stok s CROSS JOIN
     mermer_cins m JOIN
     stok_durum d
     ON s.stok_durum_id = d.stok_durum_id
WHERE m.mermer_cins_id = '5' AND s.blok_no = 'M6320'
GROUP BY s.bundle_no, s.boy, s.yukseklik, s.hatali;
```

If you do want all (matching) rows from `s` and `m`, you can use a subquery rather than a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT s.*, m.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM stok_durum d
        WHERE s.stok_durum_id = d.stok_durum_id
       ) as stok_adet
FROM stok s CROSS JOIN
     mermer_cins m
WHERE m.mermer_cins_id='5' AND s.blok_no='M6320'
ORDER BY s.blok_no ASC, s.bundle_no ASC, s.stok_tarih DESC
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your interest. I tried sql in. but repeated data is coming.
Mysql comes with 25 lines of data, Mssql comes with 45 lines of data.

Mssql ss: 

https://i.ibb.co/61sF59c/Ekran-Al-nt-s.png


Mysql ss: 
https://i.ibb.co/fkZxJhm/Ekran-Al-nt-s-2.jpg